# what does "behind" mean in source tree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to git community,  and I use source tree to visualize it but I wonder what is the meaning of "behind" as you can see in the picture [image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means the upstream “develop” branch (the branch that your “develop” branch is tracking; probably named something like “remotes/origin/develop” in your repo) has eight commits that your “develop” branch doesn't have. The upstream “feature/XXX” branch has one commit that your “feature/XXX” branch doesn't have.

```
             _ your “feature/XXX”
            |   _ upstream “feature/XXX”
            |  |
            v  v
          ,-o--o
         /
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o
        ^                       ^
        |                       |_ upstream “develop”
        |_ your “develop”
```

Comment: Well, I moved to the develop branch and pulled from the server and "8 behind" diapered, but "1 behind" still exist. what is this supposed to mean ?

Comment: When you pulled, it fast-forwarded your “develop” to the same commit as the upstream “develop”. Your “feature/XXX” branch is still one commit behind the upstream “feature/XXX” branch.

Comment: Thanks, the graph is a perfect illustration.

Comment: Upvoted for the excellent ASCII art :)